# How to add pre-populated list of Countries , States and cities in Angular 1.x.x

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

I am searching for thirdparty directive , node package or mongooDb for Countries , States and cities to populate my Angular form , my web app is based on MEAN Stack.

Answer (score 0):

How about [countryjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/countryjs)? It seems to have what you are looking for.

I also found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/) with some very raw data. It might suit you in order to do some testing.

```
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ashmore and Cartier Island", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", ...

/ States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah ...
s_a[2] = "Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber ...
```

Comment: countryjs , I already tried , isnt returning states for any country other than USA